# detect host os ubuntu core from script

Tags: scripts, ubuntu-core

Is there a preferred way to detect in a script that the host is Ubuntu Core as opposed to another Ubuntu?

I have an ubuntu core 16 on an Edge Gateway from Dell. /etc/lsb-release says it is 16.04 LTS Xenial.

I thought about testing if the snap command exists but I think that could be installed on a regular ubuntu configured to build snaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd appreciate hearing if anyone else has a better answer.

It appears that the version option to the snap command should only work for snap on ubuntu core, and furthermore it should return "series 16". So using something along the line of:

```
if [ -x snap ] && snap version 2>/dev/null | grep -Eqs 'series +16'; then
```

Should do the trick (I just typed that in so be sure to test in your code).